# Angular translate preferredLanguage is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

```
'use strict';

angular.module("Demo", ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'controll', 'factors', 'filteer'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$translateProvider', function ($routeProvider, $translateProvider) {

        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: 'i18n/',
            suffix: '.json'
        });

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
        $translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();
        $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en-US');

        $routeProvider
            .when('/page1', {
                templateUrl: 'Main.html',
                controller: 'myCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    message: function (messageService) {
                        return messageService.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            })
            .when('/page2', {
                templateUrl: 'page.html',
                controller: 'myCtr'
            });
    }]);
```

In angular js translate preferredLanguage is not working properly in IE.When i reload the page it showing the page correctly, but while its executed its shows empty page.This code works finely in firefox and chrome only issue is in IE.In IE also once i reload the page its working and shows the content,but while initial loading there is a trouble.I also used fallback that also fails.

Comment: What IE version are you running? Try it with other versions of IE. Maybe it's something version specific.

Comment: Does the developer console say anything?

Comment: @rpadovani i didn't get any issue in console of IE and i'm using IE 11.0.32 which is the latest version